# Iterating through a list Python SQL

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to search a database, by iterating through a list of search values. I'm almost there as this works for integers but not strings. The code below won't work, but if I replace the list values with numbers it does:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

lst = []

select_query = "SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE content LIKE "
ids = ["apple", "pear"]

for x in ids:
    var = select_query + str(x)
    
    mycursor.execute(var)
    lst.extend(mycursor.fetchall())

print(lst)
```

Comment: prefer using prepared statements like in the below answer, rather than usin concatenation which might cause vulnerability to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What do you want to select with `LIKE` ? All fruits where _content_ is exactly equal to `'apple'` or where it contains the keyword `%apple%` matching also `'pineapple'` ? Why not `WHERE content IN ('apple', 'pear")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have to enclose strings in quotation marks in SQL. So for example

```sql
SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE content LIKE 'pears'
```

will work, and it will only work with the single quotations around "pears". Even better, type conversion can (and should) be done automatically with psycopg2:

```py
select_query = "SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE content LIKE %s"
...
mycursor.execute(select_query, (x,))
```

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#strings-adaptation